# Rails: link_to delete from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I have a like button that allows you to like foods. When you try to unlike the food, I get this error:

```
The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController
```

I'm not sure why it is looking for the destroy action in the users controller. My only guess is because the button is on the user show page, so I assume it defaults to that controller, but how would I access the delete method from my votes controller?

```
 Shared like form

 <% unless current_user.votes.empty? ||  current_user.votes.pluck(:food_id).include?(food.id) %>
     <%= form_for @vote do |f| %>
       <%= f.hidden_field 'food_id', food.id %>
       <%= f.hidden_field 'user_id', food.user.id %>
       <%= f.submit "Vote", :class => "like_button" %>
     <% end %>
 <% else %>
     <% vote = food.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first %>
     <div class="unlike_button">
     <%= button_to "Unlike", vote,  method: :delete %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

def index
 @votes = Vote.all
end

def new
 @vote = Vote.new
end

def create
 @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)

if @vote.save
  puts @vote
    flash[:notice] = "Thanks for voting!"
  redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
else
  puts "No"
    flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong"
  redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  end
end

def destroy
   @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
   if @vote.destroy!
    flash[:notice] = "Unvoted!"
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
   end
end

private

def vote_params
  params.require(:vote).permit(:food_id, :user_id)
end
end
```

---

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :food
end
```

Comment: Try `<%= button_to "Unlike", vote_path(vote),  method: :delete %>`